# Pandas read_hdf5 partial matching of a string

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I have a database with about 20K records and I want to use hdf5 instead of sql to query it as it seems quicker. However, I want to use a `LIKE`-like syntax to do it, but it seems that `pandas.read_hfd5` can just find exact matches.My code snippet is as follow.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_hdf("test.hdf5",'myTable', where="name = %r" % query)
```

For example if the user enter `user1` or `User1` or `USER1` it should return the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible because you can only use the functions listed in the last paragraph of [pytable condition syntax](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/condition_syntax.html#condition-syntax). A (not very pretty) workaround for **this particular** case in your example would be `where="name= %r or name= %r or name= %r" % (query.upper(),query.capitalize(),query.lower())`

Comment: Hi Stef, thanks for your comment. I will probably just go with the capitalize option then, as my DB has capitalized names.